# how to have Diff retry attempts for diff exceptions while implementing non blocking retry mechanism?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-retry

I have a requirement where I need to have diff retry attempts for messages of the same topic based on diff exceptions i.e 3 Retry attempts for timeout exception with a delay of 5 min and 10 retries for Pending exception(custom exception) with a delay of 1hr. Both exceptions can occur as part of the consumer but one at a time.

I am exploring RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder and trying to extend this with my own class
i.e CustomRetryTopicConfigurationBuilder

```
@Data
public class CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder extends RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder {

private int maxAttempts;
public CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder retryOn(List<Class<? extends Throwable>> throwables) {
    for (Class<? extends Throwable> throwable : throwables) {
       super.retryOn(throwable);
        if (throwable.isInstance(TimeoutException.class)) {
            this.maxAttempts(3);
        } else
            this.maxAttempts(10);
    }
    return this;
}

public static CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder newInstance() {
    return new CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder();
}

@Override
public CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder maxAttempts(int maxAttempts) {
    this.maxAttempts=maxAttempts;
   return this;
}
```

}

RetryTopicConfig class as :

```
public class RetryTopicConfig {

@Autowired
KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration retryConfigOne() {
    RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration= CustomRetryConfigurationBuilder
            .newInstance()
            .retryOn(List.of(TimeoutException.class, PendingException.class))
            .fixedBackOff(5000)
            .includeTopic("retry_test")
            .useSingleTopicForFixedDelays()
            .create(kafkaTemplate);
    return retryTopicConfiguration;
}
```

}

But still, it is taking attempts as 3 and after digging more inside abstract code came to know that creating a method of RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder does all these setups of topic creation i.e destinationTopic and its properties.

So has anyone faced the same kind of problem and what will be the solution I can implement?

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported - you would need a different retry topic chain for each interval - otherwise something with a short interval could be behind a record with a longer interval.

You can, however, mix blocking and non-blocking retries (with different back offs), based on the exception type.

Comment: we just changed the sol as it's getting difficult to implement like this. Now we need to handle only pending cases, we ignored timeout one's and handled through another approach. But for pending cases we want to retry after 12 hours like we have main topic and consumer of that main topic is calling status checkk api and if status comes as pending then we are pushing that record to new topic "main-topic-pending" and after 12 hr need pushing same record to main topic. This is what we are thinking. If you can sugest better way of doing then that will be helpful.